# Creating a List in RF using RIDE editor

Tags: robotframework

Basically I am trying to make a List using Create List Keyword from BuiltIn Library 
${strValue}    **Create List**    q    r    s    1

I get an output as 
[u'q', u'r', u's', u'1']

I am actually looking for the output to be printed as
[q, r, s, 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never get the output to look literally like `[q, r, s, 1]` because that is not how python lists work.

However, you can easily create your own function which takes a list variable and returns a string in that format.

For example:

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    ${data}=     create list    q  r  s  1
    ${converted}=    convert list data    ${data}
    should be equal as strings    ${converted}    [q, r, s, 1]

*** Keywords ***
convert list data
    [Arguments]   ${list}
    ${result}=    evaluate    "[" + ", ".join($list) + "]"
    [return]      ${result}
```